# GridView: Using RecyclerView or Simply TextView with clickable words

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview, spannablestring, clickablespan

So, Does anybody know how to create following grid? I need to set clickable event to every word:

[image: pic 1]

If four words are not fit to a line then should be shown three in a line:

[image]

if it will be exceed to a line n words then should be shown n words in a line.
Is there anybody knows how to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SpannableString and ClickableSpan. this Activity, for example, creates TextView with your text and manages clicks on each word:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Activity activity;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity = this;
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        String text = "up down Antidisestablishment over took dropped lighten with from throught fell on up down Antidisestablishment over took dropped lighten with from throught fell on";

        String[] textArray = text.split(" ");

        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);

        int start = 0;
        int end = 0;

        for(final String item : textArray){

            end = start + item.length();
            ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Say " + item+ "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                    super.updateDrawState(ds);
                    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                }
            };
            ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            start += item.length()+1;
        }
        textView.setText(ss);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }
}
```

and here is activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorLink="#000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

if you click on any word you get popup with this word

EDIT: to justify the text use the library [android-justifiedtextview](https://github.com/ufo22940268/android-justifiedtextview)

But not the library from gradle, there are the old version which does not support `SpannableString`. I recommend just copy the class `JustifyTextView` from git to your project. Then you can use this view in your `.xml` like:

```
<com.yourdomain.yourproject.JustifyTextView
  android:id="@+id/textView"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="24sp"
  android:textColor="#000000"
  android:textColorLink="#000000"/>
```

here is what I got with this library:
[image: justified text]

you also can modify the library to keep last line unjustified. Every word in the text is still clickable.

Comment: Thanks for answer Alexander, but I need to locate words as how image is looked. I need show words as justify style.

Comment: I don't use html, and I tried TextJustify-Android, but didn't help

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of items you have to add is little, consider using a [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout). It extends a LinearLayout, so just wrap it in a `ScrollView`, add your views to it dynamically, and you should be good to go.